# Run an animation on background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, background-process, flutter-animation

I need to run animation on the background. So that even if the user navigates to other pages the animation will keep on running. I achieved the animation(ken burns effect) with the following code:

```
ClipRect(
    child: Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(translation.value, 1.0),
      child: Transform.scale(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
        scale: scale.value,
        child: Image.file(File(widget.image)),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

I need to run the animation on the background to capture frames and convert a still image to video. So the plan is to keep the animation running on the background and use [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package to capture frames of the invisible widget.

Unfortunately, animation stopped when I navigated to another page, and still frames were captured.